# building android 2.1 (eclair) from source

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build Android 2.1 from source using the instructions given [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Compile_CyanogenMod_for_Dream_%26_Sapphire)

However, when I run repo sync it exits with an error that says:

```
error: revision eclair in Cyanogenmod/android external webkit not found.
```

Does anyone have any idea about why this might occur?

Answer (score 0):

There's at least a typo.  I see Cyanogenmod in the error message where it should probably be Cyanogenmod

Also the instructions you refer to appear to be for Froyo.  Eclair may or may not work with these instructions.

Comment: Hi, Yeah that was A typo. fixed it. about the instructions i guess if we change the keywords like - cupcake,eclair,froyo,gingerbread we can get the versions we want. currently the post shows gingerbread which was froyo before.